# 'have the time' vs 'have time'

Tags: articles, american-english, definite-article, phrases

I would like to use the phrase "Have you had time to look at my draft?" in American English, and I'm wondering if I need to use "the" before time.

I couldn't found an explicit answer to my question.

I found this discussion: [enter link description here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-time-or-time.1876711/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are idiomatic. Without the article is less common. *Enough time** is also frequent.